# can we include jquery inside a java script validation function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript validation function and a jquery progress bar.
onclick of a button it is doing some validation and then some long database query in the background.I want to have a progress bar when this query is going on as well as that JavaScript function to execute before the back-ground process starts.
here is where it is calling JavaScript function

```
<input name="btnPublish" class="button1" type="button" id="btnPublish" value="Publish" onClick="disableActiveButtons()">
```

my jquery is like::

```
$('#btnPublish').click(function() { 
                     var val = 0;
                     var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
                     val = val+1;    
                     $('#pb').progressbar({ value: val});   
                     $('#percent').text(val + '%'); 
                     if(val == 100){
                         clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                     }, 50);
                     });
```

can i include this jquery inside the JavaScript validation function so that both of them works?
if not how should i implement so that I have progress bar and JavaScript validation too?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you call disableActiveButtons() from within $('#btnPublish').click ??

Comment: not clear how to call.I have a js file ui.js which is my jquery.I'm including this file in my jsp using <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/ui.js"></script>. This jsp has a button (id="btnPublish") and onclick of which it is calling the JAvaScript function disableActiveButtons().
now how do i do so that on click of button it goes to jquery and then calls the Script? Please tell me how do i call  disableActiveButtons() from within $('#btnPublish')

Comment: got it i can call :) but now how do i know that the background processes complete and have to stop progress bar

Comment: Which server technology J2EE , ASP.Net , PHP ? You need to send something(session variable , hidden field etc) in response to the client to show the successful database operation.

Comment: Its J2EE application,actually after validating it is invoking a shell script and after completion it is giving success page.So till the success pages comes I want to disable my screen or have some progress bar running

Comment: Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the javascript function from within your JQuery onClick you would do :

Remove onclick attribute fom the input tag :

```
<input name="btnPublish" class="button1" type="button" id="btnPublish" value="Publish">
```

And call the function as :

```
$('#btnPublish').click(function() { 

                 if(!disableActiveButtons()) 
                     return false; //cancel the event if validation failed , else continue 
                 var val = 0;
                 var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
                 val = val+1;    
                 $('#pb').progressbar({ value: val});   
                 $('#percent').text(val + '%'); 
                 if(val == 100){
                     clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                 }, 50);
                 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Muse!! few more questions,how to implement  this progress bar run such that it appears like a dialog box which will run till the background process completes(a huge background process) and disappear when background process is finished.

Comment: Assuming you have implemented async call to perform background task , you might want to send a variable in response indicating that the task has been completed and check for the variable from client side to stop progress bar . Though you didn't mentioned what technology you are using on server side.

Comment: This works once, but if you want professional code you need to be able to call an external javascript function from multiple locations. This solution will force you to inline dozens of this identical function. Are you saying it is not possible to get a general answer to this problem?